# JAVA Compilation program

Tags: java

```
  public class FindTop {

    private int[] numbers;

    public FindTop(int[] numbersArg){
        this.numbers = numbersArg;
    }

    public int findHigher(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex){
        int top = this.numbers[lowerIndex];
        for(int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++){
            if (top < this.numbers[i]) 
                top = this.numbers[i];
        }
        return top;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myNumbers[] = {10, 5, 2, 4, 8};
        FindTop numbers = new FindTop(myNumbers);
        System.out.println( numbers.findHigher(1, 4));
    }
}
```

As I'm new to java, I wasn't able to get the code, I was trying to execute, I get this error :

Could you suggest me where I was going wrong. 
compilation info

```
Main.java:1: error: class FindTop is public, should be declared in a file named FindTop.java
public class FindTop {
```

Comment: What is unclear in "*class FindTop is public, should be declared in a file named `FindTop.java`*"?

Answer (score 3):

In java, you have to name your file the same as your public Class. In your case, the file that you saved should be called **FindTop.java** capitals and all.

> Each source file can contain one public class. The source file's name
>   has to be the name of that class. By convention, the source file uses
>   a .java filename extension (a tail end of a file name that marks the
>   file as being of a particular type of file.)

For the capitalization part, make it a habit to **always** capitalize the file name the same was as your class name. (`FindTop` and not `findtop`). On some systems, it won't matter, but on many it will throw errors if the capitals are different.

---

[Here](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.ca/2011/01/javas-file-names-and-class-names.html) is some more explanation.